# Can't run Liferay over HTTPs

Tags: java, tomcat, https, liferay

I have used keytool to create a selfsigned certificate for development purposes. I used the resulting keystore to run a regular Tomcat 7 instance through HTTPS, and everything worked fine with this config:

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keyAlias="myalias" keystoreFile="c:\keystore.jks" keystorePass="mypass"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

But when I use the same snipped of configuration to run my Liferay through HTTPs, I get an `ERR_SSL_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY` on Chrome.

My liferay instance is version 6.1.1 which includes a Tomcat 7.0.27 and a 1.6JRE. Could this be related to the error? If so how can I tell my Liferay instance to use the JDK 1.7?

Command used to create the certificate:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myalias -keyalg RS
A -keystore c:\keystore.jks -storepass mypass -validity 360
```

Comment: Can you post the command that you have used to create the self-signed certificate? It's not necessary post critical information, I just want to see the crypto stuff

Comment: @JohnnyWiller I just did

Comment: Which version of java have you used?

Comment: It seems Liferay was using 1.6. I managed to change it to 1.7 and now its working, but in my production environment I can't do that. Is there a way to get this working with 1.6?

Comment: I mean to run keytool, have you tried run keytool with java 7 and use generated jks on liferay?

Comment: Yes, I used 1.7 to generate the certificates

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related with JVM version, **the official way to fix it is updating Java**. I've found an workaround, but I higly encourage you to don't use it, try to convince yourself or your boss that update Java is the best way.

If you can't convince then try this:

Inside Connector tag, put:

```
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
```

like

```
<Connector port="8443" ... ciphers=... />
```

If also don't work, you can try remove some `..DHE..` ciphers on the list above.